# Unlimited buffering in terminal window of Turbo C++

Tags: c++, buffer, turbo-c++

When I run the code below in TurboCPP (GUI version)

```
#include<iostream.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
602
603
604
...
999
1000
```

Clearly, the earlier prints from 1 to 601 have been erased and I can't scroll back indefiniely.
I am using Turboc++ IDE(GUI version).
Is there any I can allow unlimited buffering with turbo c++ compiler?
For example, in BlueJ IDE of java for example there is a "unlimited buffering" option.

Comment: I would honestly recommend switching to a more modern compiler and IDE, turbo C++ is really old. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961828/why-not-to-use-turbo-c?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and editing, but at this point I am not really doing anything  advanced. And it's version 4.5 I believe. So it's probably the latest version among turboc++. I don't see why such a simple problem cannot be addressed.

Comment: This really isn't a C++ question at all. It's entirely about Turbo C++ usability

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a TurboC problem. The lines were dropped by your terminal window because of scroll limit. Try to increase the scroll limit (Windows DOS window or Linux terminal).

Comment: I have no idea how to increase the scroll limit. Plus, my version is GUI version of TC++ , not the DOS, so does increasing the DOS window limit really help? And like I said, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Did you try to run your binary in a dos box?